# How to filter these arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following arrays:

```
const players = [{
        id: 1,
        ip: '198.199.162',
        nickname: 'BIG BOSS'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        ip: '198.199.162',
        nickname: 'CHICKEN LITTLE'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        ip: '198.199.162',
        nickname: 'MR T'
    }, {
        id: 4,
        ip: '198.199.162',
        nickname: 'DONUT KING'
    }];

const connectedRooms = [{
        playerId: 4,
        roomId: 1,
        playedTime: 300

    }, {
        playerId: 2,
        roomId: 1,
        playedTime: 30
    }, {
        playerId: 1,
        roomId: 2,
        playedTime: 10
    }, {
        playerId: 3,
        roomId: 3,
        playedTime: 45
    },
   {
        playerId: 1,
        roomId: 3,
        playedTime: 15
    }

const rooms = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'READY SET GO'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'CHICKEN WINNER'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'BURGER TIME'
    }];
```

I need to filter those arrays in a way that I could tell what room has the player played in. My desired output would be the following:

```
{
   key: BIG BOSS,
   value: [CHICKEN WINNER, BURGER TIME]
}
```

So far my code is only listing the IDs of the rooms. I have tried ES6 filter but I only get the room Id as well.

```
let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < connectedRooms.length; j++) {
                if (connectedRooms[j].playerId === players[i].id) {
                    result.push(connectedRooms[j].roomId);
                }
            }
        }
```

How else could I filter these arrays to obtain the desired output?

Comment: What's wrong with what you already have?

Comment: Need to filter them out by player, so I can know which rooms have the player connected to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = [];
players.forEach(player=>{
    value=[];
    rooms.forEach(room=>{
        if(connectedRooms.filter(connectedRoom=>connectedRoom.playerId==player.id&&connectedRoom.roomId==room.id).length>0) value.push(room.name);
    })
    if(value.length>0) result.push({key:player.nickname,value:value});
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you :

```
// for each players
players.map((player) => {
    return {
        key: player.nickname,
        value: connectedRooms
            // filter connectedRooms where the player is
            .filter((connectedRoom) => {
                return player.id === connectedRoom.playerId;
            })
            // for each filtered connectedRooms, you search room's datas
            .map((connectedRoom) => {
                return rooms.filter((room) => {
                    return room.id === connectedRoom.roomId;
                }).pop().name; // i used `pop` assuming your datas can't have players connected to non-existent room
            })
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get all room names from the `connectedRooms` according to the `playerId` then assign the room names into `value` property. In the end, `getRooms` returns an object holding all target data structures by `playerId`.

```
const getRoomNames = (playerId) => connectedRooms.reduce((acc, cr) => {
    if(cr.playerId === playerId) {
        const roomName = rooms.find(room => cr.roomId === room.id)?.name;
        acc.push(roomName);
    }

    return acc;
}, []);

const getRooms = () => players.reduce((acc, player) => {
    acc[player.id] = {
        key: player.nickname,
        value: getRoomNames(player.id)
    }

    return acc;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code.

```
let result = {};
const playerId = 1;
const key = players.filter(val => val.id == playerId).map(val => val.nickname);
const value = connectedRooms.filter(val => val.playerId == playerId).map(val => rooms.filter(value => value.id == val.roomId)[0].name);
result = {key, value};
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that loops through each array once, using reduce.

1. Finds the user id.
2. Turns `rooms` into an object with `roomObj[id] = name` so I can do a look up instead of looping over `rooms` again and again.
3. Builds a new array of `playerRooms`, filtered by `playerId`, by adding the room name from `roomObj`.

```js
function getRoomsBasedOn(nickname) {
  // 1
  let user = (player) => { return player.nickname == nickname };
  let id = players.find(user).id;  // crashes if nickname not found

  // 2
  let roomObj = rooms.reduce((obj, room) => (obj[room.id] = room.name, obj) ,{});

  // 3
  let playerRooms = connectedRooms.reduce((arr, room) => {
    return (room.playerId == id) ? arr.concat(roomObj[room.roomId]) : arr;
  }, []);
  
  return {
    'key': nickname,
    'value': playerRooms
  };
}

const players = [{
        id: 1,
        ip: '198.199.162',
        nickname: 'BIG BOSS'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        ip: '198.199.162',
        nickname: 'CHICKEN LITTLE'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        ip: '198.199.162',
        nickname: 'MR T'
    }, {
        id: 4,
        ip: '198.199.162',
        nickname: 'DONUT KING'
    }];

const connectedRooms = [{
        playerId: 4,
        roomId: 1,
        playedTime: 300

    }, {
        playerId: 2,
        roomId: 1,
        playedTime: 30
    }, {
        playerId: 1,
        roomId: 2,
        playedTime: 10
    }, {
        playerId: 3,
        roomId: 3,
        playedTime: 45
    },
   {
        playerId: 1,
        roomId: 3,
        playedTime: 15
    }];

const rooms = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'READY SET GO'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'CHICKEN WINNER'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'BURGER TIME'
    }];

console.log( getRoomsBasedOn('BIG BOSS') );
```